# Python App to Provide SSO via OneLogin Example - how to move to production?

Tags: python, saml, onelogin

I need to convert our django website to saml service provider so that it would be possible to login into it using OneLogin for our enterprise clients.

I explored and repeated all 6 steps of https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python

It is working, but I can not understand how to migrate from this example to production website:

Task 2: Create an app connector in OneLogin - do we (website owners) need to have onelogin account with application created in it? If yes, then what type of application we must use when creating this app? In the example there is "SAML Test Connector (IdP w/ attr) app". But how to be on production? What app type must be used here?

Task 5: Add users to your app connector - in the example Default role is used and example is working - I can login using same credentials as I used for creating application in step 2. But how to be on production? Must we use some other role? Must admins of our clients do some steps in their onelogin control panel to give access to our website to their users? Must we somehow give access to each client admin? How can we detect organization, user belongs to, after he logined into our website via onelogin?